# How to use OwnsOne and OwnsMany function in EF Core 7 to store an array of string json in a column?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I want to achieve something like this:

| name | tags |
| --- | --- |
| first | ["tag#1", "tag2"] |
| second | ["tag#1", "tag2", "tag3"] |

This is the entity type, `Category`:

```
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the configuration:

```
builder.OwnsMany(category => category.Data, b =>
     {
         b.ToJson();
     });
builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(450);
```

But I get the following error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'string'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type

Comment: Mapping collections of primitive types to JSON is not yet supported.

Comment: Either use value converter, or make a Tag entity (with Id and Text properties).

Comment: EF-Core 8x supports this now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77714233/298573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom converter to convert array primitive data type. Here uses `Newtonsoft.Json`. You can use `System.Text.Json` instead.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(s => s.PrimitiveArray).HasConversion<JsonPrimitiveTypeConverter>();
}

public class JsonPrimitiveTypeConverter : ValueConverter<List<string>, string>
{
    public JsonPrimitiveTypeConverter() : base(
            d => d == null
            ? default
            : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d),
        d => d == null
            ? default
            : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(d))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally used MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.ValueConversionExtensions that has HasJsonConversion method that actually does that. but your solution works too, thank you.