# Configuring JSON Column for string list in EF with IEntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm excited about Entity Framework's JSON column support. However, I'm having issues configuring my entity to make use of it. Here's my entity, simplified for clarity:

```
public class Bill : EntityBase
{
    public DateTimeOffset BillDate { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    public DateTimeOffset? DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    public IList<string> OrderNumbers { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public IList<string> CustomerOrderNumbers { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

I use `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` to configure my entities because I find I get a lot of granularity in how the tables get set up. Here's the corresponding Configuration:

```cs
public class BillConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bill>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bill> builder)
        {
            // Primary Key
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasColumnOrder(0);

            // (snipping audit and version columns)

            // Property settings
            builder.Property(x => x.BillDate)
                .HasColumnOrder(6);

            builder.Property(x => x.DeliveryDate)
                .HasColumnOrder(7);

            builder.Property(x => x.OrderNumbers)
                .HasColumnOrder(8);

            builder.Property(x => x.CustomerOrderNumbers)
                .HasColumnOrder(9);
```

However, when creating my initial migration, it throws the following error:

```
The property 'Bill.CustomerOrderNumbers' could not be mapped because it is of type 'IList<string>', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

The error makes sense but I'm not sure where the 'support' comes in. I made a converter:

```cs
public class StringListValueConverter : ValueConverter<IList<string>, string>
    {
        public StringListValueConverter()
            : base(
                value => JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
                dbValue => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<string>>(dbValue, JsonSerializerOptions.Default) ?? new List<string>()
            )
        {
        }
    }
```

Then I was able to use `.HasConversion<StringListValueConverter>()` on the columns, per [this blog post](https://medium.com/@shahabganji/store-array-of-strings-with-ef-core-cosmosdb-8c69321b3983).

I'm failing to understand where EF's new 'functionality' is. Couldn't I always have done this? Is there a simpler way to do this without the manual conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have missed the conversion call. Here's an example in .NET 6; please feel free to use it.

Context file:

```cs
  // builder
  model.Entity<Bill>()
    .Property(t => t. OrderNumbers)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
    .HasJsonConversion();
```

Extension methods:

```
  public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
  {
    var converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>(
      v => JSerialize(v),
      v => JDeserialize<T>(v));

    var comparer = new ValueComparer<T>(
      (l, r) => JSerialize(l) == JSerialize(r),
      v => v == null ? 0 : JSerialize(v).GetHashCode(),
      v => JDeserialize<T>(JSerialize(v)));

    propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
    propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
    propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);

    return propertyBuilder;
  }
```

note: change the json converter.

Comment: Nice, would the addition of a comparer help when sorting columns that used this conversion?

Comment: @Killnine that is for comparing your custom types [check here for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5), but you could use the value converter for this purpose. I hope this helps.

Comment: UPDATE: This is now solved via EF-core 8 natively and doesn't require an extension method. I highly recommend moving to @VahidN's solution now.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm failing to understand where EF's new 'functionality' is

This is understandable since at this time the official docs are still not updated, and the "new functionality" is only explained in the "What's new" section for EF Core 7 - [JSON Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns).

The functionality is supposed to be activated *only* for owned entity types (`OwnsOne` / `OwnsMany`) with `ToJson()` fluent API for the corresponding builder.

However, the docs say

> Note
>
> Mapping collections of primitive types to JSON is not yet supported. The document above uses a value converter to transform the collection into a comma-separated string. Vote for [Json: add support for collection of primitive types](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28688) if this is something you are interested in.

Which simply means you cannot use it for your `string` lists and should resort to the old good value converter. At least in EF7. According to the linked GitHub issue, it has been implemented in upcoming EF8. How - I don't know at this time, EF8 is not released yet, and I have a strong policy for not trying/testing preview software.

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanation of "owned" entity types now makes it click.

Answer (score 2):

[Now it's possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/#queryable-primitive-collection-columns) to store lists of simple types as JSON with EF-Core 8x:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In this case the `tags` will be stored as: `["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]` in the database and working with it doesn't need any converters.

Comment: Does this require any special notation on the EntityTypeBuilder? In th elink you posted I didn't see that they did anything special to configure the Type to get this working.

Comment: No. It will be handled automatically.