# Storing string list in EF7 JSon Comun

Tags: entity-framework-core

If the property I am marking with `OwnsOne ... ToJson` is a list of strings, the EF7 will serialized it like this: `{ Capacity: 4 }`, and no items, no nothing. I can work it around with `HasConversion`, but still...
Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77091148/configuring-json-column-for-string-list-in-ef-with-ientitytypeconfiguration/77091933#77091933 Especially *"Mapping collections of primitive types to JSON is not yet supported"* citation.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for pointing me to this. Voted for it.